# category.php template is not working instead index.php works?

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, posts

in WordPress posts the template category.php is not working instead index.php works for archive and category pages . So i can't get the categories in the index.php template file properly.

`get_the_category()`; and `get_query_var()` are not working in this page.

I just want a category page for my WordPress posts using `category.php` or `index.php`.
Can someone help please?

Comment: Does your `header.php` has the `wp_head()` function?

Comment: yes it has the wp_head() function.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the answer you're looking for but in my case, it was enough of a solution to use archive.php instead.

That same page will load for author and other archive. But for me that worked as I'm just using category.

UPDATE:

Also works by using categories.php instead of category.php (Or archive.php)